# Is Chrome extension Content Script scope shared when opening a new tab with window.open (since Chrome 45)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which used to work fine until the latest update to Chrome (45).

The problem is that the content scripts that used to load separately for each tab, now seem to share scope between an opened tab and its opener tab (when using window.open), as long as the new tab is on the same domain as the opener.

The interesting thing is that this wasn't the case until today, when my Chrome was updated to the latest stable version (45), yet I wasn't able to find anything in the release notes about this (could very well be I missed it).

My question is whether this is indeed a change with the new Chrome? And if it is, how can I prevent this from happening or work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what your content scripts do there could be different ways to tackle the problem.

So far I've noticed that in Chrome 45 `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message:"text"})` sent to `tabId` is received also by this tab's opener tab's content script and the workaround is (implying you want to send the message to the main frame's content script):

```
try {chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message, {frameId: 0})} // throws on Chrome prior to 41
catch(e) {chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message)}
```

I think this is a bug and evidently it was introduced in [this fix](https://codereview.chromium.org/1225413002) of [this bug](https://crbug.com/507461).

Comment: this might be it. I do see the message sent to the opener which might be the explanation. I will try your code and update here later. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working. Thanks for the quick and useful answer!

Answer (score -4):

You have not stated any information regarding the extensions other than a few of its functionalities. However, if you simply need the extension to work and require and looking for a stable environment, **I suggest you stick to the version of the web browser you know best**, and you are experienced with. No need to keep following the updates all the time. **The change you are experiencing may be just a deprecated code that needs a patch.**

Also, I have not had the time to inspect all changes in chrome 45, however,the major change I witnessed, is the tab loader standby(nothing new to firefox).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since my extension is used by other users (customers) not updating the browser is a non option. I cannot control thier browser version.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, apologies.

Comment: My bad, I didn't think to mention it. Thanks anyways for taking the time to reply.